# pattern match get list and dict from string

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have string below,and I want to get list,dict,var from this string.
How can I to split this string to specific format?

```
s = 'list_c=[1,2],a=3,b=1.3,c=abch,list_a=[1,2],dict_a={a:2,b:3}'

import re
m1 = re.findall (r'(?=.*,)(.*?=\[.+?\],?)',s)
for i in m1 :
    print('m1:',i)
```

I only get result 1 correctly.
Does anyone know how to do?

```
m1: list_c=[1,2],
m1: a=3,b=1.3,c=abch,list_a=[1,2],
```

Comment: Why cant you simply split on comma and then split individual strings to get, list, vars and dict?

Comment: you mean  [list_c,=,1,2....etc] then recursive to handle this?

Comment: That might be a much simple way

Comment: What is your end goal with what you are trying to do? Typically, when it comes to wanting to convert strings to variables, it would be a better approach to actually use a dictionary instead. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) should give a good explanation. Or even, how are you getting this data? Can it be structured differently to help your solution?

Comment: @VivekKhurana There are stray commas in the lists and in the dictionary.

Comment: @idjaw  that doesn't matter someone has already answer my question below.

Answer (score 2):

Use '=' to split instead, then you can work around with variable name and it's value.

You still need to handle the type casting for values (*regex*, *split*, *try* with casting may help).

Also, same as others' comment, using dict may be easier to handle

```
s = 'list_c=[1,2],a=3,b=1.3,c=abch,list_a=[1,2],dict_a={a:2,b:3}'
al = s.split('=')
var_l = [al[0]]
value_l = []

for a in al[1:-1]:
  var_l.append(a.split(',')[-1])
  value_l.append(','.join(a.split(',')[:-1]))
value_l.append(al[-1])

output = dict(zip(var_l, value_l))
print(output)
```

Comment: I think split '=' is the keyword in this problem!!Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck if you more or less explicitly describe the right-hand side expressions: numbers, lists, dictionaries, and identifiers:

```
re.findall(r"([^=]+)=" # LHS and assignment operator
                  +r"([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|" # Numbers
                  +r"[+-]?\d+\.|" # More numbers
                  +r"\[[^]]+\]|" # Lists
                  +r"{[^}]+}|" # Dictionaries
                  +r"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*)", # Idents
           s)
# [('list_c', '[1,2]'), ('a', '3'), ('b', '1.3'), ('c', 'abch'), 
#  ('list_a', '[1,2]'), ('dict_a', '{a:2,b:3}')]
```

Comment: thanks you so much!!
BTW,if has some value without '=' how to handle this situation like
s = 'list_c=[1,2],Record,Save'

Answer (score 0):

The answer is like below

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
s = 'list_c=[1,2],a=3,b=1.3,c=abch,list_a=[1],Save,Record,dict_a={a:2,b:3}'
m1 = re.findall(r"([^=]+)=" # LHS and assignment operator
                  +r"([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|" # Numbers
                  +r"[+-]?\d+\.|" # More numbers
                  +r"\[[^]]+\]|" # Lists
                  +r"{[^}]+}|" # Dictionaries
                  +r"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*)", # Idents
           s)
temp_d = {}
for i,j in m1:    
    temp = i.strip(',').split(',')       
    if len(temp)>1:
        for k in temp[:-1]:
            temp_d[k]=''
        temp_d[temp[-1]] = j
    else:
        temp_d[temp[0]] = j
pprint(temp_d)
```

Output is like

```
{'Record': '',
 'Save': '',
 'a': '3',
 'b': '1.3',
 'c': 'abch',
 'dict_a': '{a:2,b:3}',
 'list_a': '[1]',
 'list_c': '[1,2]'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of picking out the types, you can start by capturing the identifiers. Here's a regex that captures all the identifiers in the string (for lowercase only, but see note):

```
regex = re.compile(r'([a-z]|_)+=')
#note if you want all valid variable names: r'([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|_)+'
cases = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(regex, s)]
```

This gives a list of all the identifiers in the string:

```
['list_c=', 'a=', 'b=', 'c=', 'list_a=', 'dict_a=']
```

We can now define a function to sequentially chop up `s` using the 
above list to partition the string sequentially:

```
def chop(mystr, mylist):
    temp = mystr.partition(mylist[0])[2]
    cut = temp.find(mylist[1])           #strip leading bits
    return mystr.partition(mylist[0])[2][cut:], mylist[1:]
mystr = s[:]
temp = [mystr]
mylist = cases[:]
while len() > 1:
    mystr, mylist = chop(mystr, mylist)
    temp.append(mystr)
```

This (convoluted) slicing operation gives this list of strings:

```
['list_c=[1,2],a=3,b=1.3,c=abch,list_a=[1,2],dict_a={a:2,b:3}',
'a=3,b=1.3,c=abch,list_a=[1,2],dict_a={a:2,b:3}',         
'b=1.3,c=abch,list_a=[1,2],dict_a={a:2,b:3}',
'c=abch,list_a=[1,2],dict_a={a:2,b:3}',
'list_a=[1,2],dict_a={a:2,b:3}',
'dict_a={a:2,b:3}']
```

Now cut off the ends using each successive entry:

```
result = []
for x in range(len(temp) - 1):
    cut = temp[x].find(temp[x+1]) - 1    #-1 to remove commas
    result.append(temp[x][:cut])
result.append(temp.pop())                #get the last item
```

Now we have the full list:

```
['list_c=[1,2]', 'a=3', 'b=1.3', 'c=abch', 'list_a=[1,2]', 'dict_a={a:2,b:3}']
```

Each element is easily parsable into key:value pairs (and is also executable via `exec`).